# UIView presenting UIViewController with delegate

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller, delegates

I have a `UIViewController` that pops up a custom `UIView` that needs to be able to present another `UIViewController` (*BarcodeScanViewController*).

When the user is done with the `BarcodeScanViewController`, data is passed back to the `UIView` to update a label.

How can I present the `BarcodeScanViewController` from the `UIView` with the a navigation bar so I close it if necessary?

The below code kinda works. It present the `BarcodeScanViewController`, but it doesn't actually do anything. Its just a black view.

***Inside Custom UIView***

```
- (void) startScan {

    BarcodeScanViewController * bsvc = [[BarcodeScanViewController alloc] init];
    bsvc.delegate = self;

    UIViewController *currentTopVC = [self currentTopViewController];
    [currentTopVC presentViewController:bsvc animated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

I also receive an warning

Assigning to

> 'id < BarcodeScanViewControllerDelegate > ' from incompatible type 'CustomView * const__strong'

when I try to assign the delegate.

I have never called UIViewController from a UIView before. I know that only a VC can call another VC. So I tried to create VC to use a presenter.

***What am I doing wrong?***

Comment: Please explain what you do in `currentTopViewController`. How do you get the view controller that presents the new one? Something like `[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] rootViewController]`? It's typically not trivial for a view to try to figure out what view controller is currently the top most, as actually it should usually not need to know. I suggest you make a property out of it with a decent default (like I wrote here) and set the controller from outside the view if needed.

Comment: I was trying to use currentTopViewController to get the VC that instantiated the custom view.

Comment: Yes, I got that, the question is how you're trying to do that. The warning comes from your class not adopting the `BarcodeScanViewControllerDelegate` protocol btw. Also, getting a black screen indicates you're not totally off, maybe the said controller just doesn't configure its view correctly? (note: setting its main view's background color to transparent can do that. You won't actually see the "previous" controller's view under it). Your code above can't show me what's wrong. Using another VC to present the new one is the right idea, though.

Comment: I did adopt the delegate in the .h file. I have used the Barcode VC in other apps. Called from other VC's but never a UIview

Comment: If you adopted the delegate in the header the warning should disappear. Of course I'm assuming you also implemented the required methods, btw. Re: the `BarcodeScanViewController` - the code you posted is correct, if `currentTopViewController` is set correctly. Getting a navigation bar requires that everything is in a `UINavigationViewController`, or you  present one that has the `BarcodeScanViewController` as its root. There's a bunch of ways for all that. What causes the black screen can not be deducted from above code. Can you provide a sample project via github or so to let me investigate?

Comment: @Gero thanks for taking a look, a skeleton is here [link](https://github.com/adammcelhaney/ViewControllerTest) I think I fixed the Delegate error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, there were a bunch of smaller things. I forked your repo and fixed it so that you can see how it works. See [here](https://github.com/GeroHerkenrath/ViewControllerTest).

In short: You did present the scanner VC, but as I said you can't simply put it "over" the presenting view controller (your ViewController class). As soon as any presentation transitions (i.e. animations) are done, the view of that ViewController is removed from the view hierarchy. So what you saw as a black screen was just the window background (which is black). The scanner's view was transparent. Furthermore, the scanner expected you to provide a view to render the camera into (and buttons) via an IBOutlet. Since you didn't instantiate the controller from a storyboard, you didn't set any, i.e. the view used for that was nil and thus the frame the scanner wanted to render the video in had a size of (0, 0). 
I fixed that for now, hopefully you can now see how presenting a viewcontroller is supposed to work. To achieve an actual popup (with "underlying views of previous view controllers") is a bit harder on iOS, but possible in several ways. I can elaborate further later if you want.

Comment: Wow thanks so much for taking some time to help me learn and understand! I am looking at your revisions and comments now!